# How to select item from drop down menu using Selenium with Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have a drop down menu and need to select an item based on its value.
let's say I want to select value "50.0"
[image]

full HTML of the table is at the end of the post:
below code can work based on the ID (but the problem is that everytime I reload the page the ID changes so I have to update it in my code).

```
                width = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#linemodechannelwidth > tbody > tr > td.dijitReset.dijitStretch.dijitButtonContents > div.dijitReset.dijitInputField.dijitButtonText > span")
                actions3 = ActionChains(browser)
                actions3.click(width).perform()
                time.sleep(4)
                spacing50 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#dijit_MenuItem_27_text')
                spacing50.click()
```

what should be the code to use to select the value 50.0 from the dropdown box based on its value and not the ID ?

Below is the HTML of this dropdown menu:

```
<table class="dijit dijitReset dijitMenuTable dijitSelectMenu dijitValidationTextBoxMenu dijitMenu dijitMenuPassive" role="listbox" tabindex="0" cellspacing="0" id="linemodechannelwidth_menu" widgetid="linemodechannelwidth_menu" style="top: 0px; visibility: visible;" aria-labelledby="linemodechannelwidth">
          <tbody class="dijitReset" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode"><tr class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" role="option" tabindex="-1" id="dijit_MenuItem_27" aria-label="50.0 " aria-disabled="false" widgetid="dijit_MenuItem_27" aria-selected="false" style="user-select: none;">
          <td class="dijitReset dijitMenuItemIconCell" role="presentation">
                         <span role="presentation" class="dijitInline dijitIcon dijitMenuItemIcon dijitNoIcon" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode"></span>
          </td>
          <td class="dijitReset dijitMenuItemLabel" colspan="2" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode,textDirNode" role="presentation" id="dijit_MenuItem_27_text">50.0</td>
          <td class="dijitReset dijitMenuItemAccelKey" style="display: none" data-dojo-attach-point="accelKeyNode" id="dijit_MenuItem_27_accel"></td>
          <td class="dijitReset dijitMenuArrowCell" role="presentation">
                         <span data-dojo-attach-point="arrowWrapper" style="visibility: hidden">
                                       <span class="dijitInline dijitIcon dijitMenuExpand"></span>
                                       <span class="dijitMenuExpandA11y">+</span>
                         </span>
          </td>
```

37.5
              
              
                             
                                           
                                           +
                             
              

              
                             
              
              62.5
              
              
                             
                                           
                                           +
                             
              

              
                             
              
              75.0
              
              
                             
                                           
                                           +
                             
              

              
                             
              
              87.5
              
              
                             
                                           
                                           +

Comment: Do you have the link to this website?

Answer (score 2):

for example: let's assume the dropdown has an id "12345"

and there is :

```
< option value="x"> A < /option> 
< option value="y"> B < /option>
< option value="z"> C < /option>
```

first capture the options in selenium:
=> **options_list = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("1234")));**

if you want to select by visible dropdown item : (lets say "A" )
=> **options_list.selectByVisibleText("A")**

if you want to select the item by dropdown number  (lets say second item)
=> **options_list.selectByIndex(1)**

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement

### Find the table first 

table = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(
'table.dijit.dijitReset.dijitMenuTable.dijitSelectMenu.dijitValidationTextBoxMenu.dijitMenu.dijitMenuPassive'
)

### Loop through all td in the table
for td in table.find_elements_by_tag_name('td'):
    assert isinstance(td, WebElement)
    ### If the text value cast to int is 50 click and break.
    if int(td.text) == 50:
        td.click()
        break
```

Comment: I got an assertion error .
    "assert td is WebElement
AssertionError"

should I click on the table first to open the drop menu ?

Comment: My bad, I believe it should be `assert isinstance(td, WebElement)`. Could you link the website in the question? Without that its quite difficult to see where things might be going wrong.